# GitHub action build container, cannot find requirements.txt

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a CI in GitHub. My idea is creating a python container and then installing some packages. The Dockerfile and CI.yaml are as following.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONPATH='/workspaces/PROJ-2023-MLSERN'

# install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc

WORKDIR /MLSERN

# Install pip requirements
COPY ../requirements.txt . 

RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /MLSERN
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
#
# Setup Python Environment to the Project folder

CMD ["python", "test/test_file.py"]
```

The CI configuration file is

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  run-tests:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        python-version:
          - "3.8"
    
    name: Test
    runs-on: ${{matrix.os}}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build docker images
        run: docker build - < Dockerfile
      - name: Run tests
        run: docker run python:0.0.1
```

Currently, I can see the GitHub can build the container successfully until `COPY ../requirements.txt .`. The error is `requirements.txt` is not found.

I guess there must be something wrong with either my dockerfile or the CI configuration file.

My `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt` are in the root directory. The folder structure is like

```
-repository name
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
  - .github
     - workflows
       -CI.yaml
  - src
     - main.py
  - test
     - test_file.py
```

Comment: In your `Dockerfile`, please put `RUN ls` after `COPY ../requirements.txt . `, and share the output. It will verify whether `requirement.txt.` is copied to your container from local.

Comment: So now the error is at the line ```COPY ../requirements.txt  . ```, the error is ```"/requirements.txt": not found```. The error is the same if I change the code to ```COPY requirements.txt . ```.  There is no error if I use ```COPY . .```. But then the ```RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt``` outputs the error. I used ```RUN ls ```, the output is empty. I guess I didn't copy the repository files to the container?

Comment: Yes, seems your folder structure is having issues. Can you bring `requirement.txt` file to the location where `Dockerfile` is located?

Comment: They are at the same location. They are all at the root directory of the repository. This Dockerfile can build a container with no issues in  VSCode. Do I need to specify a path in CI.yaml?

Comment: I am not familiar with Github CI, but in GitLab, if you need to build a docker image. You need to register a docker based runner and give proper instruction to build it.